# Why is my drop down menu working offline but not on my server?

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

so if you go [here](https://www.leeshewan.tech) and click contact, it should show a google map but for some reason it doesn't.

The weird thing is that if I open the contact.html file, it works fine, so it's only on the website that it doesn't work.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I would love the help!

Comment: Why does it say the website is unsafe and hackers may be trying to steal my personal info? Also, where is your code? Is it on this apparently suspicious website?

Comment: It's because it's a .xyz domain. I can move it to my .tech domain and that shouldn't give a warning if you don't trust it. I thought it would be best for whoever answers to just see the source code using view source as I'm using bootstrap so it's not my code that I'm using. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: There, I changed it to my .tech domain, please let me know if this is still giving warnings as it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.leeshewan.tech/contact.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=56.506174,79.013672&t=m&z=4&output=embed'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

You have to serve the map over https i think. Change that somehow :)

Change the url somewhere in your code :

`http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=56.506174,79.013672&t=m&z=4&output=embed`

into

`https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=56.506174,79.013672&t=m&z=4&output=embed`

hope to help

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mixed content issue, it looks like you didn't include your jquery path properly. Note that this URL is inaccessible: https://www.leeshewan.tech/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js

The jquery file is referenced in your index page as `vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js`. Remember to upload that file to your server, using the same relative path to your index file, or the page will break (the slider is broken, for instance).

You should your use web browser's `Developer Tools` to view syntax issues, javascript errors, and network requests. This will greatly aid debugging your web applications.